# twig template to fetch details of linked nodes

Tags: theming

I have a content page say content type "spl content" which has few related pages(added using field entity reference). when i create page in admin I can link multiple pages to my page using  entity reference which i call in this specific case as related pages.

I have custom template for content type "spl content", here I get all the node ids of related pages but I want to access further details of the related pages.

Is it possible in twig template having path themes/custom/{themename}/templates/node--spl-content.html.twig to fetch details of related node?

I do get node ids of related pages by looping node.field_related_pages

```
{% for item in node.field_related_pages %}

{{item.entity.id}}

{% endfor %}
```

item.entity.id prints the node id of every related page. I need to have body content and other field of related page in this twig.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `{{ item.entity.body.value }}` `{{ item.entity.field_name.value }}`

Comment: This should rather be a block display via a block reference field than done with templating.

Comment: Yes that works thank you